# plotting area betwwn implicit curves

Tags: python, manim

I am trying to create a picture which shows area between two implicit functions and the horizontal rectangles. I am using Manim community edition.

The following code is giving error messages on area and dA variables.

```
from manim import *

class GraphAreaPlot(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        ax = Axes(x_range=[0, 4], y_range=[-1.5, 1.5])

        curve_1 = ax.plot_implicit_curve(lambda x, y: y**2-x+1, color=BLUE)
        curve_2 = ax.plot_implicit_curve(lambda x, y: y**2+x-3,  color=GREEN)

        area = ax.get_area(curve_2, (1, 3), bounded_graph=curve_1, color=GREY, opacity=0.5)
        dA = ax.get_riemann_rectangles(
             curve_1, bounded_graph=curve_2, y_range=[-1, 1], dy=0.2, color=RED, fill_opacity=0.5)

        self.add(ax, curve_1, curve_2, area, dA)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use `get_area`, you have to change the plots from implicit to explicit ones (which is possible for the implicit functions you have specified). Determining the area currently is not supported for implicit plots.

Alternatively, you could also construct the area manually by constructing an appropriate `Polygon` (see [the implementation of `get_area`](https://github.com/ManimCommunity/manim/blob/2275ec5916de0ad3bedbc276da09fc3bfbae4d5e/manim/mobject/coordinate_systems.py#L1183) for inspiration).

Comment: In this case, I need to create 4 curves, two for above the x-axis and 2 for below the x-axis. Then three areas to shade the bounded region. But how to implement get_riemann_rectangles horizontally? Do you have any code as a working example of this type?